# Firewall aliases mapped on DNS entries in pfsense

Tags: domain-name-system, port-forwarding, pfsense, aliases

Is there a way, in PfSense, to add aliases to the firewall, based on hostnames registered in the DNS server?

What I want to achieve is to setup a port forwarding rule, using pure NAT, to `PC1.example.com`, but PfSense says (same with only `PC1` in the target field):

```
"PC1.example.com" is not a valid redirect target IP address or host alias.
```

Comment: I wish :( I can't find a way

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message. Use "host alias"!

- Go to Firewall > Aliases > IP
- Click "Add".
- Give it a spunky name like "MY_FIRST_ALIAS"
- Keep the Type at "Host(s)"
- Below at the "Host(s)" section add your "PC1.example.com" in the "IP or FQDN" field.
- "Safe"
- "Apply Changes"
- Go to Firewall > NAT
- Add your NAT rule and as a "Redirect Target IP" you can now chose

  - Type: "Single host"
  - Address: "MY_FIRST_ALIAS"

That's it. Pfsense will refresh the DNS resolution of "PC1.example.com" periodically and will update the NAT and Firewall rules accordingly.